# How can I open, edit and save a word document with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

I want to get a word document from data base by ASP.Net and show it on Internet Explorer, then I want to edit some text and replace this document with the original one, exactly same as Sharepoint.

Comment: I am looking for the same solution except I am using WinForms.

Answer (score 3):

Man `Word` understands that the document is from `Sharepoint`. You will need a lot of plumbing like services to take care when the file is changed by user (like file system watcher to watch when file is modified) and then upload it back to server.

I think SharePoint is already good at this and you should figure out to fit it into your strategy to use it for this kind of things.